# Cordova BUILD FAILED : specified for property 'resDir' does not exist

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new using cordova, I have create project

```
$cordova create helloworld
$cordova platform add android
```

And I changed project properties `target=android-22` to `target=android-19` on `C:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\project.properties` and also `C:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties`

And then I try to run on emulator but get this error:

```
c:\android_project\helloworld>cordova emulate --target=android_19 android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "c:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\cor
dova\run.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\cordova\android\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator
Running: c:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -
b c:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=x8
6 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':CordovaLib:processDebugReso
urces'.
> Directory 'C:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\in
termediates\bundles\debug\res' specified for property 'resDir' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.375 secs

c:\android_project\helloworld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "c:\android_project\helloworld\pl
atforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\android_project\helloworld\platforms
\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=x86 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
 code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Have I missed something? I have googled it for hours but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else...
I determined that I could resolve this problem by creating the

```
android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/res
```

directory mentioned in the error - just empty.

Then I could proceed with that error disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

some of Cordova Java files need api 21 or above.when you want to change target you can use android manifest xml file.